# Como adicionar nova propriedade a classe GMSMarker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, maps

Como adicionar uma nova propriedade a esta classe.

Adicionei ela no arquivo GMSMarker.h, mas ao tentar usar a nova propriedade recebi este erro:

> -[GMSMarker setIdRegistro:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x790cd410 2015-02-27 13:26:44.340 TesteEstacionamento[7174:108607]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMarker setIdRegistro:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x790cd410'

Comment: Algum motivo especial para você querer alterar a classe da própria biblioteca do Google Maps? Não sei se é possível da forma que você quer.

Comment: Sim adicionar mais um atributo para salvar uma informação relacionada ao local onde ele indica no mapa. 

Jaja irei mostrar como fiz. Mas não é nada demais.

Comment: Utiliza o atributo que existe no GMSMarker chamado `userData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver declarando uma nova classe, herdando GMSMarker.

Na declaração da nova classe incluí a nova propriedade desejada, e depois a sintetizei.

```
MeuMarker.h

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface MeuMarker : GMSMarker

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* idRegistroTocado;

@end
```

MeuMarker.m

```
#import "MeuMarker.h"

@implementation MeuMarker

@synthesize idRegistroTocado;

@end
```

Utilização

```
MeuMarker* marker = [[MeuMarker alloc]init];

marker.position = position;
marker.title = dadosRegistros.nome;
marker.snippet = dadosRegistros.rua;
marker.idRegistroTocado = dadosRegistros.idRegistro;
```

Comment: Você poderia simplesmente ter usado o atributo: `userData`

Comment: Eu nao sabia deste atributo, ate procurei algo sobre mas nao encogrei. Mas eu precisei usar mais de uma nova informacO. E deste modo pude expandir a utilizacao. Mas se este atributo fot um NSMutableArray, vou considerar seu uso em projetos futuros e ate mesmo ma atualizacao deste. Obrigado!

Comment: Sim, na verdade trabalha como o `NSDictionary`, chave - valor, possibilitando vários atributos, um exemplo: `marker.userData = @{@"store":info};`

Comment: Otimo! Obrigado @Gian! Vou adicionar a resposta!!